# Using XSLT how to find the first element of a node

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<ZoneLane>
    <OriginDestinationPointTypeCode>Z</OriginDestinationPointTypeCode>
    <ZoneLaneReference>ALL</ZoneLaneReference>
    <CountryCode>**</CountryCode>
    <CountryName>ALL</CountryName>
    <Zone>ALL</Zone>
</ZoneLane>

<ZoneLane>  
    <OriginDestinationPointTypeCode>Z</OriginDestinationPointTypeCode>
    <ZoneLaneReference>032</ZoneLaneReference>
    <CountryCode>**</CountryCode>
    <CountryName>ALL</CountryName>
    <Zone>32</Zone>
</ZoneLane>
```

The code I used is:

```
<xsl:variable name="svAllZoneOnly">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test ="ZoneLane[*[2]] and not(ZoneLane/ZoneLaneReference = 'ALL')">
            N
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            Y
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

I need to define a variable which returns 'Y' when only Zone 'ALL' is present. Not when i have a combination of Zone 'ALL' + other zones.

Is there any solution?

Comment: **1.** What is your context node when you are defining this variable? -- **2.** What in your example qualifies as "other zones"? I see only one `Zone` element.

Comment: Zonelane is the context node.  The Zonelane can have one or more Zone elements. In this example we have 'ALL' Zone and Zone : 32. But i need to check only when 'ALL' zone is present exclusively.

Comment: Is your question not answered? If not, why not?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
test ="Zone[. = 'ALL'] and count(Zone) = 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

`$X//Zone[.='ALL'] and not($X//Zone[. != 'ALL'])`

where `$X` defines the scope within which the condition must be true.

Unlike the answer from @michael.hor257k, this answer will give true if there are two Zone elements that both have the value 'ALL'. We're both guessing as to exactly what condition you want to test.

Comment: We have only two cases: 1. Only One 'ALL' Zone   2. 'ALL'  Zone(Always one in number)+ Other Zones(Can be one or more in number. In the  example given:its 32). I want to test only when its exclusively 'ALL' Zone

Comment: @Lisa Actually, in your example you have a third case: no 'ALL' Zone + other Zone.

Comment: Yes..you're right. Apologies for missing that scenerio.